# How to update a variable using the get package with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm experimenting a bit with `flutter` and the [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx) package and so far I like it. The only problem I have at the moment is that I cannot understand how to update an `obs` variable with a new value instead of just incrementing it as described in the tutorial:

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}
```

In my case, I have a variable called `id` in my controller which I would like to update to a brand new value when an element on my left menu is clicked. Roughly the code is the following:

my controller

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MainController extends GetxController {
  var id = 0.obs;
  setId(var newId) {
    print("Inside setId");
    id = newId;
  }
}
```

the function is called when an element of the menu is pressed

```
onTap: () {
    c.setId(this.widget.identifier);
},
```

I have a reference to the `MainController`

```
final MainController c = Get.find();
```

Currently, when I pressed on my menu I have the following error:

```
Inside setId

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
Expected a value of type 'RxInt', but got one of type 'int'
```

I tried to create an `Rx` variable in multiple ways but no luck so far.

Can anyone show me how to fix this? Is there a better way to update a variable in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created demo project with GetX. Refer this code. -> https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example

Answer (score 0):

right after I posted this question I found the solution to my problem. I'll leave the like to the answer here but in short you need to update `id.value` instead of just the id

[The more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335361/how-to-convert-rxint-to-int-in-dart-flutter)